# Emails stop on Exchange 2003. Have to reboot daily

Tags: exchange

im not an exchange expert but have been left holding the baby so to speak. At the moment we have a problem where emails stop being received almost daily. I can RDP into the server, all processes are running and there is plenty of storage. The server isn't using all its system resources and its the enterprise edition so no 75gb limit. Any ideas guys what could be up as a reboot seems to fix things ( although not for very long) any help appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the logs in the event viewer would be a start.

Comment: Does the server respond on port TCP:25 when you experience the problem?

Comment: ...and if it responds, what does it answer if you speak SMTP to it?